# What will be the set of all possible values of the following expression

Tags: linear-algebra

for $x, y, z$ which are non zero real numbers

$\dfrac{|x + y|}{|x| + |y|} +\dfrac{|z + y|}{|z| + |y|}+\dfrac{|x + z|}{|x| + |z|}$

How do I solve such problems?

Comment: What IS the problem here?

Comment: Maybe something is missing, such as some inequalities or equations relating $x,y,z$, and maybe you want the maximum of your expression? Anyway as it stands no one could guess what the question is.

Comment: User153671 Do you want to find the minimum of the expression? If so that should be added to your question.

Comment: Now at least the heading makes the problem specific, however I'd suggest that part should be in the body of the question as well.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if none of $x,y,z$ are $0$ then at least two have the same sign. Also note that if say $x,y>0$ then $|x+y|/(|x|+|y|)=1.$
Also if $x,y<0$ we again have $|x+y|/(|x|+|y|)=1.$ So the sum of the three terms must be at least $1$. Since at $(x,y,z)=(1,1,-1)$ 
the sum is $1$ (two of the terms are $0$), we can say that the minimum of the expression is $1$. If we use all three of $x,y,z>0$
the sum of the three terms is $3$, which is the maximum of the expression.

A way to see clearly that the maximum is $3$ is to use the triangle inequality. Each numerator is then at most the corresponding denominator, so each of the three terms is at most $1,$ making the sum of all three terms at most $3.$ Now if one takes $x=y=1,$ and graphs the expression as a function of $z,$ one sees it takes on all values in the closed interval $[1,3].$ The resulting function of $z$ is 
$$\frac{2|z+1|}{|z|+1}+1.$$ This is continuous and takes on $1$ at $z=-1$ and $3$ at $z=1.$